# Scope in coffeescript classes

Tags: javascript, scope, coffeescript

I would like to nest a number of functions inside a class property as shown below.
Unfortunately, they won't get access to the main scope of the class.

Can I solve this without passing each nested function a reference to `this`?

```
class myClass

  constructor: -> @errors = []

  doSomething: -> @errors.push "I work as expected"

  functions:
    doStuff: ->
      @errors.push "I cant access @errors" # => TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

    ugly: (context) ->
      context.errors.push "It works, but I am ugly" # Works fine but requires scope injection
```

Non-working alternative using suggested fat arrow:

```
class myClass
  constructor: ->
    @errors = []

    @functions:
      doStuff: =>
        @errors.push "I wont work either" # TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
```

Optional alternative, which doesn't write to the global `this.errors` property:

```
class myClass

  constructor: ->

    @functions =
      errors: []
      doStuff: ->
        @errors.push "I will write to functions.errors only"
```

Comment: Binding them to this/@ in the constructor?

Comment: You mean `constructor: -> @errors = [] @functions: doStuff -> ...` ?

Comment: Maybe using the fat arrow => http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow I'm not a coffeescript master, sorry :)

Comment: Me neither. Tried fiddling around with it but couldn't get it working though.

Comment: Updated my post with how I tried using it.

Comment: If nothing else helps, you can use javascript's own `bind` function on each item in your `functions` array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript (as the result, CoffeeScript too), methods use `this` of the object that contains method.

```
method()                  // this == globalObject
object.method()           // this == object
Math.random()             // this == Math
```

This usually works well, unless you deal with example like yours:

```
object.functions.method() // this == object.functions
```

When dealing with JavaScript, I would avoid having namespace for functions - it doesn't play well, even with workarounds. For example, you could try putting reference to `this` object in `object.functions`, so any function in `object.functions` would have access to it.

```
class MyClass
  constructor: ->
    @errors = []
    @functions.self = this

  doSomething: ->
    @errors.push "I work as expected"

  functions:
    alsoDoSomething: ->
      @self.errors.push "Also works!"
```

This appears to work at first, but could be confusing when you are using properties like `apply` or `call` on it, `obj1.functions.alsoDoSomething.call(obj2)` won't work as the `obj2` is not correct object (user should do `obj2.functions` instead which can be confusing).

The real solution is: *don't*. JavaScript isn't intended for abuse like this. All object methods should be directly in object prototype. If you have object in it, all methods of it aren't methods of your object.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to GlitchMr's answer, I'll explain why each of your attempts failed.

1. The `functions` object is declared on the prototype, so `@errors` is compiled to  `myClass.errors`. However, the `errors` object is declared as an instance member, not a    prototype member.
2. You define `functions` using CoffeeScript's function notation, when it should be an object. The error message is a CoffeeScript compiler error; after fixing this syntax error, it works like it should!
3. You preface this example with why it doesn't work, so I won't tell you twice!

Here is an example of the correct use of the [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) for this circumstance.

```
class MyClass

  constructor: ->
    @errors = []
    @functions = 
      doStuff: =>
        @errors.push "I can and do access @errors"

c = new MyClass
c.functions.doStuff()
console.log c.errors # ["I can and do access @errors"]
```

Hopefully this helped demystify the errors and show the power of CoffeeScript's fat arrow!