# Callback scope not accessing function in AngularJS Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, coffeescript, promise

I have an AngularJS Service whose code is below. I make 2 Promises and then want to call a function of the service. However, due to the callback being in a different scope I am unable to proceed. Any idea how to go about this?

```
app.service "ServiceName", [                                 

  "AnotherService"                                                                
  "MyService"                                                                   

  (AnotherService, MyService) ->                                                         

    @dataFromA = []                                                       
    @dataFromB = []                                                    

    @mashupData = () ->                                           
      debugger                                                           

    @getDatafromA = () ->
      //getDataFromDBAndReturn

    @mainServiceFunction = () ->                              
      @getDatafromA().then (response) ->              
        @dataFromA = response                                          
        MyService.dataFromB().then (response) ->         
          @dataFromB = response                                           
          @mashupData() //Gives Undefined Error                                           

return                       
]
```

Ideally, in a call to mainservicefunction, I want it to get data from A, the n B                                         and then run `mashupData`, which uses `@dataFromA` as well as `@dataFromB`.

How would I go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scope in coffeescript classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987400/scope-in-coffeescript-classes)

Answer (score 2):

Just bind correct context with [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
app.service "ServiceName", [                                 

  "AnotherService"                                                                
  "MyService"                                                                   

  (AnotherService, MyService) ->                                                         

    @dataFromA = []                                                       
    @dataFromB = []                                                    

    @mashupData = () ->                                           
      debugger                                                           

    @getDatafromA = () ->
      debugger

    @mainServiceFunction = () ->                              
      @getDatafromA().then ( (response) ->              
        @dataFromA = response                                          
        MyService.dataFromB().then ( (response) ->         
          @dataFromB = response                                           
          @mashupData()                                          
        ).bind(this)
      ).bind(this)
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `.bind` in coffeescript - it's supported as part of the language. Replace all your `->` arrows (normal JS functions) with `=>` arrows (functions maintaining `this`):

```
(AnotherService, MyService) ->                                                         

  @dataFromA = []                                                       
  @dataFromB = []                                                    

  @mashupData = () =>                                           
    debugger                                                           

  @getDatafromA = () =>
    //getDataFromDBAndReturn

  @mainServiceFunction = () =>                              
    @getDatafromA().then (response) =>              
      @dataFromA = response                                          
      MyService.dataFromB().then (response) =>         
        @dataFromB = response                                           
        @mashupData() // Will corretly resolve `this`
```